# How to include ASCII code symbol in React

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way I can include an icon using ASCII code in React. I have done this in HTML and it works just fine, but when thing comes to React it just renders the whole string code

```html
<div class="page-btn">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>&#8594</span> //in html this is a right arrow, in React this is just a plain code
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline a string using javascript unicode escapes.  [Right arrow](https://unicode-table.com/en/2192/) is 2192 in Unicode hex. (0x2192 == decimal 8594)

`<span>{"\u2192"}</span>`

Answer (score 2):

Please use the ending semi-colon `;` for the hex code to get rendered.

example: `&#8594;`

See CodeSandbox example: [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/little-star-44qr3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)